# R Shiny automating selectInput() features

Tags: r, shiny

In the app.R file below, I'm trying to create a `selectInput()` box for each column name of the iris dataset.  However, I am not sure what must go in place of the ellipsis `selectInput(..., 'Sepal.Length', c(0, 1)),` in order to make it work, and I also don't like that I had to type out the name of the column itself.  Of course, I could have done something like `selectInput(..., 'names(iris)[1]', c(0, 1)),` instead, but I'm looking to create something even more automated and streamlined (i.e., writing out `selectInput(..., 'column name', c(0, 1)),` five times for each of the five columns seems grossly inefficient).  In other words, perhaps I could make Shiny automatically recognize that the iris dataset has 5 columns by default, which would create the five `selectInput()` boxes appropriately?

The whole reason why I'm trying to accomplish this is because I would like to create a simple automated character vector (shown in the code below as `vec <- c(1,1,0,0,1)   #corresponding to c(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Species)`), which automatically updates depending on whether I choose `0` or `1` in the respective `selectInput()` boxes discussed above.

Complete code (with critical sections marked with a hashtag):

```
  palette(c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#984EA3",
  "#FF7F00", "#FFFF33", "#A65628", "#F781BF", "#999999"))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # Combine the selected variables into a new data frame
  selectedData <- reactive({
    iris[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
  })

  clusters <- reactive({
    kmeans(selectedData(), input$clusters)
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 0, 1))
    plot(selectedData(),
         col = clusters()$cluster,
         pch = 20, cex = 3)
    points(clusters()$centers, pch = 4, cex = 4, lwd = 4)
  })

  #vec <- c(1,1,0,0,1)  #corresponding to c(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Species)

})


ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Iris k-means clustering'),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
    selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', names(iris),
                selected=names(iris)[[2]]),
    #selectInput(..., 'Sepal.Length', c(0, 1)),
    #selectInput(..., 'Sepal.Width', c(0, 1)),
    #selectInput(..., 'Petal.Length', c(0, 1)),
    #selectInput(..., 'Petal.Width', c(0, 1)),
    #selectInput(..., 'Species', c(0, 1)),
    numericInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 3,
                 min = 1, max = 9)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('plot1')
  )
))


# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You can use renderUI on the UI side and then generate the selectInput on the server side. Actually, using it as follows is going to work: selectInput('columnName', 'Column Name', names(iris)). Is there a reason you are trying to create a individual drop down for each of the column names?

Comment: I'm trying to create a individual drop down for each of the column names so that I can feed the character vector `vec <- c(1,1,0,0,1)` (i.e., so I can make it `c(0,0,1,0,1)` or `c(1,0,0,0,0)` or whatever, based on what I select in the drop down menu)

Comment: If you're trying to make it so that certain columns can be selected, why not do one `selectInput` with `multiple = TRUE` and then set `vec` based on the choices selected?

Comment: @brittenb Could you please demonstrate as answer?  This sounds very promising.

Comment: If you want to be able to select multiple values simultaneously, I suggest using 'checkboxGroupInput' as it is the more appropriate UI element. Yes, multiple = TRUE in selectInput will allow that as well, but that is not a proper choice in my view for this use case.

Comment: Actually, I've thought about `checkboxInput()`.  I don't think it would allow you to select either a 0 or a 1 for each column name.  Yes, you'll be able to check a column, but how do you check 0/1 for it?  In other words, once you've specified `choices`, there is no further feature to select a 0 or a 1 within a specific choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the `multiple = TRUE` value on the `selectInput` to allow for multiple columns to be selected. Then on your server side, you would just set `vec <- as.numeric(names(iris) %in% input$iris_columns)` where `input$iris_columns` refers to your `selectInput` element.

As an example:

```
ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Iris k-means clustering'),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
    selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', names(iris), selected=names(iris)[[2]]),
    selectInput('iris_columns', 'Select Columns', choices = names(iris), multiple = TRUE),
    numericInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 3, min = 1, max = 9)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('plot1')
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # Combine the selected variables into a new data frame
  selectedData <- reactive({
    iris[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
  })

  clusters <- reactive({
    kmeans(selectedData(), input$clusters)
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 0, 1))
    plot(selectedData(),
         col = clusters()$cluster,
         pch = 20, cex = 3)
    points(clusters()$centers, pch = 4, cex = 4, lwd = 4)
  })

  vec <- as.numeric(names(iris) %in% input$iris_columns)
})
```

Comment: Yes, but here you'd need to manually type out `c(1,3,4)`... the hope is that you could instead just tick boxes (or check boxes) with `selectInput()` or `checkboxGroupInput()`

Comment: No, that's just an example to show that if `x` is a vector of column names from `iris` then setting `vec` as we did gives you your results. On the UI side of your app, you'd set it up as `selectInput('iris_columns', 'Select Columns', choices = names(iris), multiple = TRUE)`. Then, once the user selects their choices, vec will be updated. No need to type out anything.

Comment: Ok, feel free to update your complete answer and I'll test it/accept it if it works.

Comment: Yes, but where is the 0/1 designation given in the code above?

Comment: Saved in `vec` as desired.

Comment: But from the code you posted, how do you know that it's 0/1, and not like 10/20 or some other set of numbers?  Or is it based on a different kind of system?

Comment: `names(iris) %in% input$iris_columns` will produce a vector of boolean values, which, when represented as numbers, are equal to 0 or 1. So this code creates a vector of booleans and then converts them to numbers. That's why we know it's 0s and 1s and not 10s and 20s.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the use of checkboxGroupInput:

```
ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Iris k-means clustering'),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
    selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', names(iris),
                selected=names(iris)[[2]]),
    checkboxGroupInput('columnNames', 'Column Name', names(iris)),
    numericInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 3,
                 min = 1, max = 9)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('plot1')
  )
))
```

To retrieve the column names selected (1) and not selected (0), you can use the following options on the server side:

```
> s <- c('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width', 'Petal.Width') # Example vector from checkbox group input
> names(iris) %in% s
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> as.integer(names(iris) %in% s)
[1] 1 1 0 1 0
> which(names(iris) %in% s) # Provides vector indices set to 1
[1] 1 2 4
> which(!names(iris) %in% s) # Provides vector indices set to 0
[1] 3 5
>
```

Comment: Yes, but when I checkbox one of the column names, it doesn't actually return a 0 or 1 into the character vector.

Comment: I suppose one option could be specify everything as 0 by default, then check whatever column names you want to be a 1.  This could be a potential workaround, but you'd need to update your answer to reflect this.

Comment: Using names(iris) %in% input$columnNames on the server side would give you a vector of column names that are selected (boolean TRUE/FALSE values). Does this work? I can update the answer.

Comment: It might actually, particularly if you specify TRUE as 1 and FALSE as 0 (or vice-versa)